# How to Decode logs data of transaction?

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I want decode logs data, I am using web3.utils.hexToAscii() method which return junk data like **!3cÀ Token create101** insted of actual data **2000 Token create 101**.

```
> {
transactionHash: '0x0d2a00b4d684efbdea26677468830d88b2145577a4b086775ebdb5189ed78d27',
transactionIndex: 0,
blockHash: '0x702e444fba974d17a9b8e881c8002e721c0517ea254991884d2ef745b7510126',
blockNumber: 2,
from: '0x21003381639c90b61ef0b1ad692078c4ee3d0a7f',
to: '0x42eb248f2dc51d6dbc13e92aed4be07291373b90',
gasUsed: 26567,
cumulativeGasUsed: 26567,
contractAddress: null,
logs: [
>     {
logIndex: 0,
transactionIndex: 0,
transactionHash: '0x0d2a00b4d684efbdea26677468830d88b2145577a4b086775ebdb5189ed78d27',
blockHash: '0x702e444fba974d17a9b8e881c8002e721c0517ea254991884d2ef745b7510126',
blockNumber: 2,
address: '0x42EB248f2DC51D6dBc13e92Aed4bE07291373B90',
data: '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',
topics: [Array],
type: 'mined',
id: 'log_985c3fd6'
>     }
>   ],
status: true,
logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000'
> }
```

I have tried below code but its return junk data.

```
function checkHex(){

    var block = web3.eth.getBlock('latest')
    block.then(block => {
      for(let txHash of block.transactions){
       let tx = web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
         tx.then(tx => {
          let receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx.hash);
            receipt.then(receipt => { 
            for(let logs of receipt.logs){
             const decoded = web3.utils.hexToAscii(logs.data);
              console.log(decoded);
>            }
>          });
>       });
>     }
>   });
> }
```

**return**

!3cÀ Token create101

**expected**

2000 Token create 101

Comment: I believe you need to reference the contract ABI (Application Binary Interface), if you intend to translate this into a human readable form.

Comment: This https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#decodeparameter is probably a good place to start.